# I cant create a page with an empty path in Django

Tags: python, django, routes, url-routing

centralsite/views

```
def centralsite(request):
    return render(request, 'centralsite/text.html', {})
```

centralsite/urls

```
 from django.urls import path
    from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.centralsite, name='centralsite'),
]
```

urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [path(' ', include('centralsite.urls')),
               path('polls/', include('polls.urls')),
               path('admin/', admin.site.urls),]
```

error message is:
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/
Using the URLconf defined in mysite.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

^$
polls/
admin/
The empty path didn’t match any of these.

how do i make this empty path work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete whitespace from your path:

```
urlpatterns = [path(' ', include('centralsite.urls')),    # bad

urlpatterns = [path('', include('centralsite.urls')),     # good
```

Otherwise, because whitespace is a character, it will look for url with whitespace or `%20`.